# closure function passing multiple arguments

Tags: javascript

Im trying to understand closures in Javascript.. I have created a function and pass 2 values (a,b)..Im wondering how inner function square(x) takes the value of a and returns its square before returning square(a) + square(b)..

In case-2, I did something similar passing (x,y) but that does not work..

Can you please explain?

Case-1

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function addsquares(a,b){
                function square(x){
                    return x * x;
                }
                return square(a) + square(b)
            }
            document.write(addsquares(2,3))
        </script>
    <head>
    <body>
    <body>
</html>
```

Case-2

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function addsquares(a,b){
                function square(x,y){
                    return x * y;
                }
                return square(a) + square(b)
            }
            document.write(addsquares(2,3))
        </script>
    <head>
    <body>
    <body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are not passing the value for `y` to `square`? may I ask why you made the change... the first one looks just fine

Comment: @Arun:In the first case, how the value of "a" was passed to x?

Comment: @user1050619 When **the `square` function was called** (in one case, `a` was used as an argument, `b` in the other).

Comment: @Arun: I dont understand,,,when you inside function can accept "x" as the "a" value, why the same does not apply to "x" & "y"

Answer (score 1):

There is no closure involved in the presented code. The *inner function is executed immediately*, passed the appropriate values from the *outer functions* parameters. It is the *result* of invoking the inner function (twice, and added together) that is returned, not a closure/function-object!

Otherwise, the arguments for closures - and here, is the secret: **closures are just function-objects created within a specific binding context** - are just like that of normal functions. Here is an example which *actually* creates a closure:

```
function multiply_over_sum(a){
    function sum(x, y) {
        return a * (x + y);
    }
    // NOW we create a closure - as a FUNCTION-OBJECT (sum)
    // is returned to the caller while maintaining access to the
    // current binding context.
    return sum;
}

// Then multiply_by5_over_sum is now a FUNCTION-OBJECT 
// that has "a" bound to the value 5.
// (It is a closure specifically because it binds to a variable.)
var multiply_by5_over_sum = multiply_over_sum(5);

// This FUNCTION-OBJECT (closure) can be INVOKED like any function
// to yield a value. In this case the values 4 and 3 are passed as
// the arguments for "x" and "y", respectively
var sum = multiply_by5_over_sum(4, 3);
```

---

While it's not strictly true (as closures bind to *variables* - not *values* - in JavaScript), the closure in the given example above can viewed as the following function:

```
var multiply_by5_over_sum = function (x, y) {
  return 5 * (x + y);
};
```

That is, only the variable bound in the closure ("a") has been captured. The parameters "x" and "y" are just that - parameters to the closure/function - and will only be bound to values when the closure is invoked, as done by `multiply_by5_over_sum(4, 3)`.